# discord.py - issues with reactions on lists

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
    elif message.contains in ["-play", ".play", "!play"]:
        print('music')
        msg = 'hi.gif'
        await message.channel.send(msg)
```

I am using the following to react to music commands - it works when a user writes `.play` etc. However, when a user writes `.play https://...` the command does not react.

I am guessing this is due to the list that is contained - anyone know how I can still get a reaction even if the words are only mentioned?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`message.contains` is a function and you are checking if that function exists in your list. Instead do-

```
elif message.content.startswith('.play') or message.content.startswith('!play') or message.content.startswith('-play'):
    print('music')
    msg = 'hi.gif'
    await message.channel.send(msg)
```

The best way to implement commands is by using `commands` extension provided with the library. [See here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/)

Comment: Thanks, that worked - the list method looks cleaner so was hoping that it would work. Thanks!

Comment: That's a bad way to implement commands even if it works, refer to the link in answer for a command module that ships with discord.py. It is much cleaner.

Comment: Is there a demo repo of reactions that I can see? All my reactions are in a huge elif chain at the moment...

I am already using cogs to split up various modules.

Comment: This guide is a good quick-start - https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/commands.html